# Uninstall binary file when removing OPAM package

Tags: ocaml, opam

Excerpt from `opam` file:

```
build: [
  ["./configure" "--prefix=%{prefix}%"]
  [make]
]
install: [make "install"]
remove: [
  ["ocamlfind" "remove" "git-lfs-server"]
]
```

It installs `git-lfs-server` binary file into `%{prefix}/bin` directory, but doesn't remove it. How to uninstall it?

`[make "uninstall"]` doesn't work.

The package is not in OPAM yet, so I test it by pinning local directory:

```
opam pin add .
opam unpin git-lfs-server
```

See [project repository](https://github.com/artemkin/git-lfs-server) and [opam file](https://github.com/artemkin/git-lfs-server/blob/master/opam) for details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove it with the following entry in the `remove` field

```
["rm" "-f" "%{bin}%/git-lfs-server"]
```

Comment: Thanks! It works like a charm! Actually, I tried `["rm" "%{prefix}/bin/git-lfs-server"]` before, but somehow missed trailing `%` :( Anyway, it is a bit confusing that I can't use `make uninstall`.

Comment: you can't use `make uninstall` since there is no more Makefile, it will deleted as soon as installation will complete.